# Rust Persistent Red Black Tree Implementation

Tags: beginner, algorithm, rust, memory-management

Below is my implementation of a persistent red black tree in Rust.

I have a few questions about potential improvements.
Currently the data and nodes are stored in referenced counted pointers. Is this the best way to do it?

On a similar note, the pattern matching statements for the balance functions are quite verbose because of the use of rc. Is there a way to write it more concisely?

Also, because I use rc pointers, should I implement the drop trait?

```rust
#[allow(clippy::module_inception)]
pub mod red_black_tree {
    use std::cmp::Ordering;
    use std::rc::Rc;

    pub enum RedBlackTree<T>
    where
        T: Ord,
    {
        Node {
            color: Color,
            data: Rc<T>,
            left: Rc<RedBlackTree<T>>,
            right: Rc<RedBlackTree<T>>,
        },
        Leaf,
    }

    #[derive(Clone)]
    pub enum Color {
        Red,
        Black,
    }

    impl<T> RedBlackTree<T>
    where
        T: Ord,
    {
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            RedBlackTree::Leaf
        }

        pub fn contains(&self, item: T) -> bool {
            match self {
                RedBlackTree::Node {
                    color: _,
                    data,
                    left,
                    right,
                } => match item.cmp(&data) {
                    Ordering::Less => left.contains(item),
                    Ordering::Equal => true,
                    Ordering::Greater => right.contains(item),
                },
                RedBlackTree::Leaf => false,
            }
        }

        pub fn insert(&self, item: T) -> Self {
            match self {
                RedBlackTree::Node {
                    color,
                    data,
                    left,
                    right,
                } => match item.cmp(&data) {
                    Ordering::Less => RedBlackTree::Node {
                        color: color.clone(),
                        data: Rc::clone(data),
                        left: Rc::new(left.insert(item)),
                        right: Rc::clone(right),
                    }
                    .balance()
                    .make_black(),
                    Ordering::Equal => RedBlackTree::Node {
                        color: color.clone(),
                        data: Rc::clone(data),
                        left: Rc::clone(left),
                        right: Rc::clone(right),
                    }
                    .make_black(),
                    Ordering::Greater => RedBlackTree::Node {
                        color: color.clone(),
                        data: Rc::clone(data),
                        left: Rc::clone(left),
                        right: Rc::new(right.insert(item)),
                    }
                    .balance()
                    .make_black(),
                },
                RedBlackTree::Leaf => RedBlackTree::Node {
                    color: Color::Black,
                    data: Rc::new(item),
                    left: Rc::new(RedBlackTree::new()),
                    right: Rc::new(RedBlackTree::new()),
                },
            }
        }

        pub fn get(&self, item: &T) -> Option<Rc<T>> {
            match self {
                RedBlackTree::Node {
                    color: _,
                    data,
                    left,
                    right,
                } => match item.cmp(&data) {
                    Ordering::Less => left.get(item),
                    Ordering::Equal => Option::from(Rc::clone(data)),
                    Ordering::Greater => right.get(item),
                },
                RedBlackTree::Leaf => Option::None,
            }
        }

        fn make_black(&self) -> Self {
            match self {
                RedBlackTree::Node {
                    color: _,
                    data,
                    left,
                    right,
                } => RedBlackTree::Node {
                    color: Color::Black,
                    data: Rc::clone(data),
                    left: Rc::clone(left),
                    right: Rc::clone(right),
                },
                RedBlackTree::Leaf => RedBlackTree::new(),
            }
        }

        fn balance(self) -> Self {
            if let RedBlackTree::Node {
                color: Color::Black,
                data: parent_data,
                left: parent_left,
                right: parent_right,
            } = &self
            {
                if let RedBlackTree::Node {
                    color: Color::Red,
                    data: child_data,
                    left: child_left,
                    right: child_right,
                } = Rc::as_ref(&parent_left)
                {
                    if let RedBlackTree::Node {
                        color: Color::Red,
                        data: grandchild_data,
                        left: grandchild_left,
                        right: grandchild_right,
                    } = Rc::as_ref(&child_left)
                    {
                        return RedBlackTree::from(
                            grandchild_left,
                            grandchild_right,
                            child_right,
                            parent_right,
                            grandchild_data,
                            child_data,
                            parent_data,
                        );
                    } else if let RedBlackTree::Node {
                        color: Color::Red,
                        data: grandchild_data,
                        left: grandchild_left,
                        right: grandchild_right,
                    } = Rc::as_ref(&child_right)
                    {
                        return RedBlackTree::from(
                            child_left,
                            grandchild_left,
                            grandchild_right,
                            parent_right,
                            child_data,
                            grandchild_data,
                            parent_data,
                        );
                    }
                } else if let RedBlackTree::Node {
                    color: Color::Red,
                    data: child_data,
                    left: child_left,
                    right: child_right,
                } = Rc::as_ref(&parent_right)
                {
                    if let RedBlackTree::Node {
                        color: Color::Red,
                        data: grandchild_data,
                        left: grandchild_left,
                        right: grandchild_right,
                    } = Rc::as_ref(&child_left)
                    {
                        return RedBlackTree::from(
                            parent_left,
                            grandchild_left,
                            grandchild_right,
                            child_right,
                            parent_data,
                            grandchild_data,
                            child_data,
                        );
                    } else if let RedBlackTree::Node {
                        color: Color::Red,
                        data: grandchild_data,
                        left: grandchild_left,
                        right: grandchild_right,
                    } = Rc::as_ref(&child_right)
                    {
                        return RedBlackTree::from(
                            parent_left,
                            child_left,
                            grandchild_left,
                            grandchild_right,
                            parent_data,
                            child_data,
                            grandchild_data,
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
            self.clone()
        }

        #[allow(clippy::many_single_char_names)]
        fn from(
            a: &Rc<RedBlackTree<T>>,
            b: &Rc<RedBlackTree<T>>,
            c: &Rc<RedBlackTree<T>>,
            d: &Rc<RedBlackTree<T>>,
            x: &Rc<T>,
            y: &Rc<T>,
            z: &Rc<T>,
        ) -> RedBlackTree<T> {
            RedBlackTree::Node {
                color: Color::Red,
                data: Rc::clone(y),
                left: Rc::new(RedBlackTree::Node {
                    color: Color::Black,
                    data: Rc::clone(x),
                    left: Rc::clone(a),
                    right: Rc::clone(b),
                }),
                right: Rc::new(RedBlackTree::Node {
                    color: Color::Black,
                    data: Rc::clone(z),
                    left: Rc::clone(c),
                    right: Rc::clone(d),
                }),
            }
        }
    }

    impl<T> Clone for RedBlackTree<T>
    where
        T: Ord,
    {
        fn clone(&self) -> Self {
            match self {
                RedBlackTree::Node {
                    color,
                    data,
                    left,
                    right,
                } => RedBlackTree::Node {
                    color: color.clone(),
                    data: Rc::clone(data),
                    left: Rc::clone(left),
                    right: Rc::clone(right),
                },
                RedBlackTree::Leaf => RedBlackTree::new(),
            }
        }
    }

    impl<T> Default for RedBlackTree<T>
    where
        T: Ord,
    {
        fn default() -> Self {
            RedBlackTree::<T>::new()
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::red_black_tree::*;
    use std::cmp::*;

    struct Point {
        x: i64,
        y: i64,
    }

    impl Point {
        fn new(x: i64, y: i64) -> Point {
            Point { x, y }
        }
        fn magnitude_squared(&self) -> u64 {
            (self.x as u64).pow(2) + (self.y as u64).pow(2)
        }
    }

    impl PartialEq for Point {
        fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
            self.magnitude_squared() == other.magnitude_squared()
        }
    }

    impl Eq for Point {}

    impl PartialOrd for Point {
        fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
            Some(self.cmp(other))
        }
    }

    impl Ord for Point {
        fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
            self.magnitude_squared().cmp(&other.magnitude_squared())
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_empty() {
        let tree = RedBlackTree::<i64>::new();
        assert!(!tree.contains(0));
        assert!(!tree.contains(5));
        assert!(!tree.contains(-20));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_insert() {
        let mut tree: RedBlackTree<char> = RedBlackTree::new();

        assert!(!tree.contains('a'));
        assert!(!tree.contains('b'));
        assert!(!tree.contains('c'));

        tree = tree.insert('a');

        assert!(tree.contains('a'));
        assert!(!tree.contains('b'));
        assert!(!tree.contains('c'));

        tree = tree.insert('b');

        assert!(tree.contains('a'));
        assert!(tree.contains('b'));
        assert!(!tree.contains('c'));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_get() {
        let mut tree: RedBlackTree<Point> = RedBlackTree::new();

        tree = tree.insert(Point::new(0, 0));
        tree = tree.insert(Point::new(1, 1));
        tree = tree.insert(Point::new(2, 2));
        tree = tree.insert(Point::new(3, 4));

        assert_eq!(tree.get(&Point::new(0, 0)).unwrap().x, 0);
        assert_eq!(tree.get(&Point::new(0, 0)).unwrap().y, 0);

        assert_eq!(tree.get(&Point::new(0, 5)).unwrap().x, 3);
        assert_eq!(tree.get(&Point::new(0, 5)).unwrap().y, 4);
    }
}
```

Edit: the rebalancing function relies is based on this diagram ([source](https://abhiroop.github.io/images/Insertion.jpg)):

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason for `#[allow(clippy::module_inception)]`?  Generally, when a lint is triggered, we fix the code rather than disable the lint.  The same goes for `#[allow(clippy::many_single_char_names)]`.  I'm scared at `from(a, b, c, d, x, y, z)`.

Comment: @L.F. for module_inception, I'm relatively new to cargo and this structure was just for practice, so I thought it would be easier to just use the same name for the project and module. For the ```from(a, b, c, d, x, y, z)``` function, I was following various guides that all used that naming scheme. I've attached at image explaining it

Comment: Right now you are defining `red_black_tree::red_black_tree::RedBlackTree`.  The correct way is to simply remove the `mod` declaration (the file is automatically a module).

Answer (score 1):

In Rust, we don't usually create the style of object where the mutation functions return new objects. Even if the internal data structure is persistent, it fits better in Rust style to have mutating functions. So your insert function might be something more like this:

```
    pub fn insert(&mut self, item: T) {
        match self {
            RedBlackTree::Node {
                color,
                data,
                left,
                right,
            } => match item.cmp(&data) {
                Ordering::Less => {
                    Rc::make_mut(&mut self.left).insert(item);
                    self.balance();
                    self.make_black();
                }
                Ordering::Equal => {
                    self.make_black();
                }
                Ordering::Greater => {
                    Rc::make_mut(&mut self.right).insert(item)
                    self.balance();
                    self.make_black();
                }
            },
            RedBlackTree::Leaf => *self = RedBlackTree::Node {
                color: Color::Black,
                data: Rc::new(item),
                left: Rc::new(RedBlackTree::new()),
                right: Rc::new(RedBlackTree::new()),
            },
        }
    }
```

The special sauce here is `Rc::make_mut`. It takes a mutable reference to an `Rc<T>` and gives you a `*mut T`. It modifies the exist item in place if it isn't shared, but if it shared it gives you a clone. This gives you the benefit of persistent data structures, clones are cheap, but still lets you avoid cloning when you don't need to.

> Currently the data and nodes are stored in referenced counted
> pointers. Is this the best way to do it?

If you need a persistent data structure,then probably yes.

> On a similar note, the pattern matching statements for the balance
> functions are quite verbose because of the use of rc. Is there a way
> to write it more concisely?

A big thing that would help is to move RedBlackTree::Node into its own struct. Then you could match the struct as a whole instead of the individual fields.

> Also, because I use rc pointers, should I implement the drop trait?

No, Rust will automatically implement the Drop trait, and the drop the rcs for you. Its pretty rare to want to implement Drop yourself.